# How to use pgf-presenter-console for presentation with changed papersize?

Tags: beamer, presentations, notes

I had to change page dimensions for a presentation but cannot use pdf-presenter-console (format of image file unknown)

```
pdfpc --notes=right Test.pdf
--notes option detected. Disable auto grouping.

(pdfpc:22079): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 16:49:03.480: gdk_pixbuf_get_from_surface: assertion 'width > 0 && height > 0' failed

(pdfpc:22079): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 16:49:03.480: gdk_pixbuf_save_to_callbackv: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed

(pdfpc:22079): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 16:49:03.481: gdk_pixbuf_get_from_surface: assertion 'width > 0 && height > 0' failed

(pdfpc:22079): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 16:49:03.481: gdk_pixbuf_save_to_callbackv: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF (pixbuf)' failed
Screensaver inhibited

(pdfpc:22079): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: 16:49:03.552: gdk_pixbuf_loader_write: assertion 'buf != NULL' failed
Could not load cached PNG image for slide 0: Format der Bilddatei unbekannt
```

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\geometry{paperwidth=24cm,paperheight=18cm}


\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
Test

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Frame 2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
3
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```